# Unable to Connect a k3s Worker to a Remote k3s Cluster in a Cloud VM

Tags: virtual-machine, kubernetes

My goal is to setup a lightweight kubernetes cluster using k3s with my server (master node) setup in a GCP virtual machine and be able to join remote agents (worker nodes) to it.

The process was successful when done with 2 VMs in the same GCP network but as soon as I attempt to join the cluster from outside of the LAN I end up with connection timeouts.

Here are the exact steps I took so far:

**On the VM (k3s server):**

1- Reserved a static external IP address

2- Added a firewall ingress rule for TCP:6443

4- Installed k3s as "server": `curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | INSTALL_K3S_EXEC="--disable-agent --write-kubeconfig-mode 644 --tls-san 35.198.xxx.xxx" sh -`

5- Exported the node token located at: `/var/lib/rancher/k3s/server/node-token`

**On the remote desktop machine (k3s agent):**

1- Installed k3s as "agent": `curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | INSTALL_K3S_EXEC="--write-kubeconfig-mode 644" sh -`

2- Attempted to join the cluster using the external IP of the VM and the exported token `sudo k3s agent --server https://35.198.xxx.xxx:6443 --token K10a3xxx::node:8b62xxx`

The output I receive after the last command is:

```
INFO[2019-10-10T15:12:54.171910055+01:00] Starting k3s agent v0.9.1 (755bd1c6)         
INFO[2019-10-10T15:12:54.172119361+01:00] Running load balancer 127.0.0.1:38669 -> [35.198.xxx.xxx:6443] 
INFO[2019-10-10T15:12:56.741810256+01:00] Logging containerd to /var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/containerd/containerd.log 
INFO[2019-10-10T15:12:56.742150259+01:00] Running containerd -c /var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/etc/containerd/config.toml -a /run/k3s/containerd/containerd.sock --state /run/k3s/containerd --root /var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/containerd 
INFO[2019-10-10T15:12:56.744248953+01:00] module br_netfilter was already loaded       
INFO[2019-10-10T15:12:56.744417346+01:00] module overlay was already loaded            
INFO[2019-10-10T15:12:56.744453854+01:00] module nf_conntrack was already loaded       
INFO[2019-10-10T15:12:56.929625073+01:00] Updating load balancer server addresses -> [10.156.0.4:6443 35.198.xxx.xxx:6443] 
INFO[2019-10-10T15:12:56.929915280+01:00] Connecting to proxy                           url="wss://10.156.0.4:6443/v1-k3s/connect"
ERRO[2019-10-10T15:15:07.362512013+01:00] Failed to connect to proxy                    error="dial tcp 10.156.0.4:6443: connect: connection timed out"
ERRO[2019-10-10T15:15:07.362608180+01:00] Remotedialer proxy error                      error="dial tcp 10.156.0.4:6443: connect: connection timed out"
```

The client indefinitely retries to connect but to no avail. It did find the correct local IP of the endpoint which shows up upon calling `kubectl get endpoints` on the VM:

```
NAME         ENDPOINTS         AGE
kubernetes   10.156.0.4:6443   19m
```

Kindly let me know if this setup I'm trying to achieve is valid and if so, what could I be missing?
Thank you.